Qt Desinger. Артефакт под курсором
Создаю интерфейс в Qt Desinger. Создано несколько вкладок/страниц. На последней созданной вкладке во время просмотра или при запуске программы при наведении курсора мышки в любое место появляется прямоугольник примерно секунд на 10. Потом он исчезает. Если перемещаю курсор в другое место, то прямоугольник появляется снова. На остальных такого нет. Не могу понять что это и причина появления. Как убрать? (курсор не отобразился при снимке экрана).

Нашел причину просмотром и сравнением свойств виджетов. Совершенно случайно. В свойстве toolTip виджета было установлено
<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>

.
